# Trying to search for all the most viewed youtube videos by title, missing search results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My goal is to find all the most viewed youtube videos with "Godot" in the title.

Using just the youtube UI I search for "Godot" and in Filters select "Type - Video" and "Sort by - View count": https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=godot&sp=CAMSAhAB

It shows me a list of videos, but many search results are missing. For example if you look at a popular Godot youtube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/uheartbeast/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid), their [most popular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAbG8Oi-SvQ) video with "Godot" in the title does appear in search results, the [second most popular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wETY5_9kFtA&t=1446s) one doesn't. Basically, some of the videos from this channel do appear on the list, but others don't (even though they have a very high view count).

When I use the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A100%2C%22order%22%3A%22viewCount%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22godot%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D) and try to do the same thing, I get the same results.

Why? Can someone help me to figure out a way to get **all** the most viewed youtube videos with "Godot" in the title?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget when looking for title containing exactly *godot* to add quotation mark around ("), then with your modified link I achieve to get both videos you specified: [https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="godot"&sp=CAMSAhAB](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%22godot%22&sp=CAMSAhAB)

However on the YouTube API the quotation mark method doesn't work.

**My solution**:

Use the following CURL request which shows in its answer both videos you mentionned:

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/search?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"context":{"client":{"clientName":"WEB","clientVersion":"2.2022011"}},"query":"\"godot\"","params":"CAM="}'
```

Note: don't pay attention to the key it's not a YouTube Data API v3 key.