# Search YouTube for video IDs, using YouTube Internal API (youtubei)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm making an android app that would search for YouTube video IDs, based on a query (a word for example).  The official YouTube API has a list() method, but it costs some quota to use (100 quota points).
After some googling, it seems YouTube also has an internal API that is usually referred to as Innertube, or youtubei. But there is no documentation about this API.

Does anyone know how can I search for video IDs using this youtubei?

As example, I tried the curl command in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938802/trying-to-search-for-all-the-most-viewed-youtube-videos-by-title-missing-search/70756481#70756481), but I got a error response:
**"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Expected , or } after key:value pair.\n022011"}},"query":""godot"","params":"CA\n**

Comment: What operating system (Debian, Windows...) and what shell (`bash`, `cmd`...) are you using?

Comment: As for the android app, I'm using Android Studio in windows.
For the example and the error response, I just try it on this online service: https://reqbin.com/curl

Comment: The problem seems to come from this online service, run the `curl` command from a shell on your OS.

Comment: I tried this in windows command prompt, and got nothing. I verified that curl works. So it's not the online service.

Comment: The command of the other post was written for `bash`, you can easily adapt it for Windows `cmd`: `curl -s "https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/search?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.2022011\"}},\"query\":\"\\\"godot\\\"\",\"params\":\"CAM=\"}"`, appending `| find /I "godot"` clearly shows that this work.